# Favorites: custom fields?

Tags: members, solspace, users

Does Solspace's Favorites module support custom fields?  Can anyone think of some other add-on or combination of add-ons that might achieve the same functionality?

I'm building a housing directory that allows users to log in and save listings they're interested in.  I've accomplished most of that using Solspace's Favorites module.  The next bit of functionality I'd like to add is for users to be able to track their progress vis a vis the application process.  Ideally, these would simply be checkboxes as custom fields attached to each favorite.  The critical bit is obviously that it's user-specific content.

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how (or if) I could structure this little bit of functionality.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: "I'd like to add is for users to be able to track their progress vis a vis the application process". Can you describe what this "application process" is? A favorite is essentially a saved entry_id. Maybe you could use a Channel Form or Freeform for your application (while passing this entry_id)?

Comment: @Solspace, that's a really good idea.  I hadn't been thinking about introducing another piece of that sort into the mix but it might just work.  Thanks for the inspiration (and brilliant add-ons)!